# Spring: Testing requestscoped bean method has been called

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, testing, spring-boot, requestscope

I'm currently using Spring Boot 1.4. I'm creating my tests but need some help on solving the following situation:

I have a request scoped bean, for the sake of simplicity, let's say it's a simple POJO with an attribute, a setter and a getter.
I want to create a test to make sure that the setter of that bean is being called once and only once along the request.

This has been my approach:

```
@Component
@RequestScope
public class MyRequestScopedBean {
    private String aProperty;

    public String getaProperty() {
        return aProperty;
    }

    public void setaProperty(String aProperty) {
        this.aProperty = aProperty;
    }
}


@Controller
public class SampleController {
    ...
    @GetMapping("/some-random-url")
    public String doSomething(MyRequestScopedBean myRequestScopedBean) {
        ...
        myRequestScopeBean.setaProperty("some random value");
        ...
    }
}

@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@WebMvcTest(SampleController.class)
@WebAppConfiguration()
public class SampleControllerTest {
    ...
    @MockBean
    private MyRequestScopedBean myRequestScopedBean;

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mvc;
    ....
    @Test
    public void aPropertySetterShouldBeCalledOnceWhenInvokingURL() throws Exception {
        this.mvc.perform(get("/some-random-url")
            .accept(MediaType.TEXT_HTML));
        verify(myRequestScopedBean, times(1)).setaProperty(anyString());
    }
}
```

However test is failing stating that "setaProperty" is never called.

I've also checked myRequestScopeBean.getaProperty value, but always returns null.

I guess the problem is that the instance of MyRequestScopeBean injected in the controller no longer exists after the "perform" ends, and, therefore, it is not the same that is injected in my test.

Is there any way I can check whether this setter method is being called along the request or not?

Thanks in advance!